# Apache Default Conf Host Binding

Tags: apache2

I have a standard apache2 installation on Ubuntu to which I have added a mysite1.com with the following:

```
 <VirtualHost mysite1.com:80>
```

Since this addition, when I call `http://<external-ip>` I no longer get the default Apache site configured at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
```

Why is `http://<external-ip>` binding to mysite.com??

I want all, non-configured `Host:` headers to hit the default and `<external-ip>` is, IMO, not configured.

UPDATE: The solution as provided by @Daniel Ferradal is to use only wildcards in *all* the `<VirtualHost *:80>` blocks and employ `ServerName` directives to do hostname mapping.

Comment: as a general practice just leave names to ServerName directive inside every virtualhost, while in virtualhost tag just use ip:port or *:port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html

> When the connection is first received on some address and port, the server looks for all the VirtualHost definitions that have the same IP address and port.
>
> If there are no exact matches for the address and port, then wildcard (*) matches are considered.

By binding your VirtualHost to a specific IP-address and port combination with `<VirtualHost mysite1.com:80>` (and none of your other VirtualHost blocks specifically and explicitly bind to  that same IP-address and port) it has precedence over the wildcard and effectively becomes the default VirtualHost (for the IP-address of `mysite1.com` and port `80`).

Comment: Is there a way to do IP-independent mapping of VHosts? I don't want to bother with IPs.

Comment: Simply use the `*` wildcard rather than IP-addresses / hostnames